# WSO2 IdentitySAMLSSOService.wsdl usage

Tags: web-services, soapui, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I would like to send a SAML Authentication Request to my WSO2 IS using the operation `authenticate()` from `IdentitySAMLSSOService.wsdl` admin services. Is there any example of usage?

After successfully configure and run the [travelocity](http://travelocity.com) sample: [docs.wso2.com](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0)

I call the authenticate() operation via SOAP UI 5.1.3. passing these parameters:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://dto.saml.sso.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:xsd2="http://util.java/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:authenticate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:authReqDTO>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:assertionConsumerURL>http://bd-vm-d-wso2bam:8080/travelocity.com/home.jsp</xsd1:assertionConsumerURL>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:certAlias>wso2carbon</xsd1:certAlias>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:destination>https://bd-vm-d-wso2is:9443/samlsso</xsd1:destination>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:issuer>travelocity.com</xsd1:issuer>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:nameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</xsd1:nameIDFormat>
         </xsd:authReqDTO>
      </xsd:authenticate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And I receive the following response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>unknown</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

On the other hand, how to send the signature of the SAML Authentication Request?
I don't see the any related parameter in the wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

Example of usage of the authenticate() web service:

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk11/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml/4.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/saml/servlet/SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java